# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 buiding on Netbeans

Tags: c++, linker

I am trying to create a simple Fix client-server using QuickFix and I have tried to implement QuickFix.Application interface.

During the building I have faced this problem : "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" and despite I have already read all the relative answers to this question and trying everything suggested I have still the above issue.

I am using Netbeans and C++, and this is the error I got

```
 g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/fix_engine_server build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/Application.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o  -lstdc++
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "FIX::Message::toString(std::__1::basic_string<char,   std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, int, int, int) const", referenced from:
 FIX::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, FIX::Message const&) in Application.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
 make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/fix_engine_server] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

On Netbeans->preferences->C/C++->C++_Compiler : /usr/bin/g++

On Property->Linker->Additional_Options : -lstdc++ 
On Property->Linker->Tool : g++

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this lib. Is it header only? Is the lib installed to a place that the link editor knows (part of the default lib search path)? Lastly, if the lib is installed, is it 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: You gave me an hint, I maybe need to build a lib in 64 bit, thank you